# My emulator is closing whenever I click the offersButton which should make the screen move to the second acitivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-virtual-device

They don't give me an error when I run the App, here is my code.

Edit 1: The logcat had the error. It was asking me at add a theme to the SecondActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Fix: Added the theme:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

Error:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7625
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.SecondActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:926)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:772)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
        at com.example.myapplication.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View.INVISIBLE
import android.view.View.VISIBLE
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val greetingTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvHello)
        val inputField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etName)
        val submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSubmit)
        val offersButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOffers)
        var enteredName = ""
        submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            enteredName = inputField.text.toString()

            if(enteredName == "")
            {
                offersButton.visibility = INVISIBLE
                greetingTextView.text = ""
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Please, enter your name!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }else{
                val message = "Welcome $enteredName"
                greetingTextView.text = message
                inputField.text.clear()
                offersButton.visibility = VISIBLE
            }

        }
        offersButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("USER",enteredName)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
        val userName = intent.getStringExtra("USER")
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOffer)
        val message = "$userName, you will get free access"
        textView.text = message
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHello"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_message"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.21" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type your name here"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.391" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.592" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOffers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View Offers"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.789"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.901" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOffer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.252"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.168" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried cold booting and using different devices. I ran on pixel 4a and the pixel 7. Both were not moving to the next screen on clicking the button. The app just closes everytime.

Comment: If the app is closing like that, you need to look in the Logcat tab in Android Studio to see why. You will find the full error message and stack trace there, which you should include in your question.

Comment: @TylerV Thanks for letting me know. I was able to fix the issue based on the error message